# relation xsp.session.timeout with server document setting

Tags: xpages

I have a question regarding the session timeouts. On the domino server in de server configuration there is a setting called  "Http Servlet session timeout". Within xpages it is possible to change the xsp.session.timeout property on the server / database to increase the time the session is being invalidated.

I would like to know if there is a relation ship between the two properties. In other words, what would happen if we set the domino servlet session to lets say 360 and the xsp property to 360 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you refer to: Server document - Internet Protocols - Domino Web Engine - Java Servlets - Idle session time-out (Notes field HTTP_IdleJSTimeout) ?  To my best knowledge, these settings are from the legacy support for J2EE Servlets 2.0 (incepted roughly at the time of the Roman Empire) and not used for the XPages Runtime at all.